# Proper way to edit an embed field

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am wondering if their is a way to edit the field of an embed that has already been sent. I want to update a field called participants with the list of people attending the embed event. Is there a way to access the previously sent embed to edit this field, or do I just need to build a new embed, and then use the .edit method on it. I also noticed that I could use a line like this `const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];` to access the embed at whatever index it is at, but the docs say that this could mess with the cache ([doc reference](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#attaching-images-2)).

Here is a snippet of my code for reference

```js
   var reactions = ['','','' ]; // Valid reactions for filter
    var participants = []; // People attending the event
    // Sending the embed back and then . . .
    message.channel.send(eventEmbed)
    .then(embedMessage => {
        // Adding the reactions after the embed has been created
        embedMessage.react("");
        embedMessage.react("");
        embedMessage.react("");
        console.log(eventEmbed);
        // Reaction Collector to gather the users attending the event.
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return !user.bot && reactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name);
        };
    
// The reactor is used to identify a new user that will be attending the event,
// and adding them to the list
        rc = new Discord.ReactionCollector(embedMessage, filter);

        rc.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            console.log(user + " reacted with a " + reaction);
            attendees.push(user); // Add new user the the attendees list
            console.log(attendees); // Debugging
            reaction.users.remove(user); // Reset reaction count back to 1

// Then here I want to edit the participants field with the new participants list
```

Any advice or pointers? I'm more so looking for examples or an explanation about the logic to go about this rather than a solution for my code, as I want to try and write it in myself :) .

I appreciate any help that can be given!

Comment: You need to create an embed object, send it in the channel, modify the embed object when you get a reaction, and then edit the message with the new modified embed.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to fetch an embed and then edit it. There is however, a way to edit it from a preexisting object.

You can keep your embed object, and when you want to update something, go to the fields property of the object, get the field you want, edit the field, and then replace your original message with the new one.

In the place where you put the `// Then here I want to edit the participants field with the new participants list`.
You should put

```js
eventEmbed.fields.find(f => f.name === "attendees").value = attendees;
embedMessage.edit(eventEmbed);
```

Comment: Would this be able to work with multiple embeds? Say, if I had 3 previously sent embeds and the 1st one had a reaction, so I update that one. Then maybe next the 3rd one had a reaction, so that one is updated, etc.

Comment: I believe it would work for as many as you want. However you should add something to stop the collection of reactions because it can stack up

Answer (score -1):

This can be very easily done! Here’s what you can do:

```
var Msg = await message.channel.send(eventEmbed)
Let x = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
//code here
Msg.edit(x)
```

You should also remember to async your message